# Can a creature with 0 power attack?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I have a creature with 0 power, can I still attack with it? I am asking in regards to Silent Skimmer but also in general.

[image: Silent Skimmer]

Comment: [There are even creatures with power less than zero.](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&power=+%3C[0])

Comment: @doppelgreener woah, I did not know that, nor did I think it could exist.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, creatures with a power of 0 can attack.  Otherwise, it would be very hard to use creatures like [Signal Pest](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSignal%20Pest%5d) which buff your team when they attack, but don't have any power of their own.

The rules just say that a creature attacks.  There's no stipulation based on power:

> 506.2. During the combat phase, the active player is the attacking player; creatures that player controls may attack. During the combat phase of a two-player game, the nonactive player is the defending player; that player and planeswalkers he or she controls may be attacked.

Comment: Or cards like Silent Skimmer, the OP's example.

Answer (score 13):

Zero power does not prevent a creature from attacking.

More generally, any creature can attack if it does not have [Defender](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Defender), has been under your control since the beginning of your turn (see [Summoning Sickness](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Summoning_sickness)) or else has Haste, and no other effect specifically restricts it from attacking. The effect will usually be obvious, like an enchantment that reads "Creatures with power {X} or less can't attack." [Reverence](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bReverence%5d) is a pretty good example of this.

> 302.5. Creatures can attack and block. [...]
>
> 508.1c The active player checks each creature he or she controls to see whether it’s affected by any restrictions (effects that say a creature can’t attack, or that it can’t attack unless some condition is met). If any restrictions are being disobeyed, the declaration of attackers is illegal.

Comment: Maybe it's useful to list Summoning Sickness as effect preventing a creature from attacking?

Comment: @steenbergh I liked the idea behind your edit, but I wanted to word it differently. Rather than list all of the different powers that are unrestricted (0, 1, 2, etc.) I would rather generalize the first sentence to cover all powers. I did that and also covered your comment, which was a good addition.

Comment: I was thinking it's weird to answer a question of "does this prevent a creature from attacking" with "these things do prevent a creature from attacking", which is subject to change. That said, now that the other answer is accepted, it's great to have this answer as well.

Comment: @TheThirdMan I challenge you to write an answer that is not subject to change. The answer may look strange to you, but all I did was generalize "zero power" to "anything not in this list". If, tomorrow, the question author wants to know if being a Wall prevents a creature from attacking, then the answer addresses that. Anyway, I edited the answer for readers who just want the quick, specific answer.

Comment: I didn't mean to criticize your approach, just state why I preferred the other answer to this one, as "there is no restriction based on power" is a lot more timeless. Yet, your answer is more useful and informative in general, so it's good to have both, and I've upvoted both of them.